# PUT request is not working in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

I have implemented this code for "PUT" request:

```
var request: NSMutableURLRequest
let url:URL = URL(string: NetworkCallSDK.sharedSingleton().urlString! as String)!
request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: (url as URL) as URL)
print("getRequestHeaderWithAllParams:\(url)")
let parameter = ["key":"STRING"] as NSDictionary

    let body = NSMutableData()
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"

    //define the multipart request type

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    for (key, value) in parameter
    {
        body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }
    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    request.httpMethod = "PUT"
    request.httpBody = body as Data
    request.timeoutInterval = 120
    return request
```

And I am getting 500 status from server. And same API is working in Android. But same code for POST method is working fine for me.

Comment: `500 status from server` . it is internal sever error

Comment: Not related but `(url as URL) as URL` is hilarious.

Comment: Actually error 500 indicates that your server have an internal error, so I would suggest that try to recheck at your backend web-services. There may be a crash or fatal error in backend code.

Comment: Not related but in Swift 3 use `URLRequest` with mutable object instead of `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Comment: ... and `Data` with `var` instead of `MSMutableData`.

Comment: @vadian but working in android.

Comment: I mean these redundant type casts are hilarious, you can simply write `var request = URLRequest(url: url)`

Comment: `body.append("\(value)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)` Are you sure about that one? What are you trying to upload exactly? What in `parameter`, what's supposed to reprendre `STRING`?

Comment: @Larme I am sending encryptedString. But its not working

Comment: I doubt your string is going to still be ASCII or UTF-8 after encryption unless your encryption is very weak (e.g. ROT-13).  You almost certainly need to convert an NSData object to a string using base64 encoding (or similar) unless you already did that conversion externally.

Comment: Also, AFAIK, the standard requires you to provide a Content-Type field for each part, not just a Content-Disposition.  That's probably the reason for the 500 error from the server.

Comment: Actually, no, now that I think about it, it's the other way around.  You should be storing the body as an NSData object to begin with, and appending the raw NSData object.

Answer (score 0):

The server is failing with an internal server error, which usually indicates either a crash or incorrectly formatted POST data.  You have two problems here:

- You're missing the Content-Type field for each of the request parts, which is required.  You should probably add something like:

  ```
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
  ```

  That's probably the cause of the 500 error.
- Your data blob is almost certainly going to show up (NULL) or an empty string unless you're pre-encoding it with base64 (or similar) outside this code.

and then send the raw data.  Otherwise, your server won't get the data.  To do this, you need to do the following:

- Use an NSData object instead of an NSString object for your body.
- Everywhere you append a string, convert it to an NSData object using the `dataUsingEncoding:` method.
- For your body data, append the actual NSData object instead of converting it to a string.
- Append the '\r\n' and separator independently afterwards.

If your server requires the data to be base64-encoded, convert the NSData to a string by calling `base64EncodedDataWithOptions:` first.  Either way, you should still be constructing the body as an NSData object.